# Adding additional video URL to video tag for browser compatibility in Elementor

Tags: video, alpha, elementor, webm, hevc

I need to use videos with alpha transparency preserved in an Elementor website and I want it to be both Chrome and Safari compatible. This is simple with HTML / CSS with video tag editing, but before I dive into coding I would like to know if I can make this possible using Elementor widgets (and additional CSS).
So basically for each video I need to put an URL for webm format and then I need to add and additional URL for hevc.mov video format.
Videos will be hosted on my S3 CDN.

Comment: If it is simple with HTML, then I guess you can just use the HTML widget in elementor

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the html video element and put it in the page using Elementor's html widget the html widget.

Something like this:

```
<video width="400" controls>
<source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

And then add it to the html widget:
[HTML Widget](https://elementor.com/help/html-widget/)